# I like the default "X" shaped crosshair cursor in linux. How do I force Debian to use that big X instead of a regular mouse cursor?

Tags: x11, mouse, cursor

Note that I do NOT want to get rid of the X crosshair. My question is: How do I force my system to use that crosshair instead of a mouse??

Answer (score 4):

In X, the cursor is set on a window-by-window basis. You can use `xsetroot` to change the cursor on the root window (the background), but each application can override this. I'm not sure which cursor you mean by *X shaped crosshair*, but maybe

```
xsetroot -cursor_name X_cursor
```

does what you want? If not, [here](http://pissedoffadmins.com/os/linux/xsetroot-cursor_name-list.html) is a list of cursor names.

Also, the window manager (WM) can provide a default cursor, and other cursor shapes when it interacts with the application. For example, in `fvwm`, `CursorStyle DEFAULT` can be used to configure the cursor. As you didn't say which window manager you use, you'll have to look it up in the documentation of your WM.

Comment: and here is a visual representation of what the cursors look like: https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/appendix/b/

Answer (score 1):

You might find this related information useful.

> Even old window managers can be tricked into using alpha cursors via
>   Xresources (unless you've disabled this functionality in libX11 - it's
>   built by default). When we first added libXcursor to Solaris about a
>   decade ago, I tested 32-bit alpha cursors in CDE with no code changes
>   with a simple:
>
> ```
> % echo 'Xcursor.theme: whiteglass' >> ~/.Xresources
> ```
>
> More info:
>
> - man Xcursor
> - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cursor_themes
> - `#ifdef USE_DYNAMIC_XCURSOR bits` in libX11 sources
>
> *Alan Coopersmith* on [TigerVNC Developer Discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/tigervnc-devel/438a259f-9e8e-d03d-c732-6abc73fc4d9b%40oracle.com)